# Leading zeros not retained reading csv with ACE OleDb

Tags: vb.net

Leading zeros not retaining while reading comma separated value(csv) file by Microsoft ACE Ole Db means if col value is 0000123456, i am getting only 123456 only, while reading programmatically in vb.net. i don't want to put any condition while preparing the comma separated value(csv) file i.e. used of apostrophe before the zeros etc.
Data structure is like below in comma separated value(csv) file

```
Name,ID
John,0001234
moon,0001235
```

but i am getting id as 1234 , 1235 but i want with zeros using Microsoft ACE Ole Db

Please guys any idea.Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is that OleDB is seeing that column as a number not string.  If you had posted code, maybe someone could tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Text File driver used by OleDb to read CSV files is unable to accurately determine the datatype of the columns. In your case, your second column is misunderstood to be a numeric column because it contains only digits, thus the leading zero are removed.

You can give a strong hint to OleDb creating a file called [SCHEMA.INI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx) that explains what is the content of the file.

In your case you could create one in the same folder of the file (I assume temp.csv for this example) and write these lines:

```
[temp.csv]
Format=CSVDelimited
ColNameHeader=True
Col1=Name Text
Col2=ID Text
DecimalSymbol=.
```

Notice that I need to specify the DecimalSymbol being a point because in my locale the comma is used as separator between the decimal and the integer part of a number (thus we use CSV files separated by semicolons)

Comment: Hi Steve ! Can u please elaborate Col1=Name Text
Col2=ID Text. mainly col1 and col2. beacuse i am getting error on the schema file

Comment: What error did you get? Accordingly to the docs, the Col1=Name refers to the name to give to the first column of your file, Text means that the column is a string column. Did you change the filename in the first line to match your filename?

Comment: yes i have changed according to my file name .now my program is reading but still i am not getting with zero  i have modified like this [1.csv]
Format=CSVDelimited
ColNameHeader=True
JobRoleNumber=JobRoleNumber Text
Title= Title Text
DecimalSymbol=.

Comment: Thanks Steve, still i am not getting with zeros

Comment: The column should be literally "Col1" and "Col2", do not put your name there. Your name goes after the equal. Col1=JobRoleNumber Text Col2= Title Text and they should be in the correct order in respect to your file (perhaps Col1 is Title and Col2 is JobRoleNumber ?)